Which Italian accent/dialect is this? Calabrian?
Is the speaker in this video speaking "standard Italian" with a Calabrian accent, or is he speaking a Calabrian dialect?
https://www.instagram.com/reel/C86puggoJvT/?igsh=MWlmeHloZ3FxbHJuZQ==
I'd appreciate any insight you can provide. Thank you so much!

Welcome to Italian.SE! I immagine it's Calabrian language.

It is Calabrian dialect, not standard Italian with Calabrian accent.

That is Calabrian, yes.
